# Hard SQL query - Rows with no matching in another table OR with items not published in another one

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my SQL I would like to execute. I'd like to avoid doing multiple requests for that and i'm pretty sure it's possible…

```
First table : products_categories (category_id, category_infos…)
Second table : products_categories_relations (product_id, category_id)
Third table : products (product_id, published, products_infos…)
```

I want to find all empty categories (no products in them) AND categories with only unpublished products. This second part is where i'm stucked.

```
SELECT pc.`category_id`
FROM `#__products_categories` AS pc
LEFT JOIN `#__products_categories_relations` pcr 
ON pc.`category_id` = pcr.`category_id`
WHERE pcr.`category_id` IS NULL
```

This query gives me categories which have no products, but i can't see how to insert a condition to say :

> **"for each category with products, return the ones which contain ONLY products where published=0"**

My analysis is :
If A is the result of the query "categories with no products"
and B is the result of "categories with only unpublished products"
I need categories that are in A OR B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT pc.`category_id`
FROM `#__products_categories` AS pc
LEFT JOIN `#__products_categories_relations` pcr 
ON pc.`category_id` = pcr.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(published) published
           FROM products
           GROUP BY product_id
           HAVING published = 0) p
ON pcr.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE pcr.`category_id` IS NULL OR p.product_id IS NOT NULL
```

The sub-query finds all unpublished products. We join with that, and then the `WHERE` clause can match either the nonexistent products with the first test, or the unpublished products with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pc.*
FROM products_categories pc
INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr
ON (pc.category_id = pcr.category_id)
INNER JOIN products p
ON (pcr.product_id = p.product_id AND published = 0)
EXCEPT
SELECT pc.*
FROM products_categories pc
INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr
ON (pc.category_id = pcr.category_id)
INNER JOIN products p
ON (pcr.product_id = p.product_id AND published != 0)
```

Essentially you query for the categories that have products with published = 0 and remove from the set all that have products with published other than 0. It will result in exactly what you need.

Note that category with products with published = 0 is not the same as empty category. If you need empty categories as well, just make a `union all`.

EDIT: 
As I was just reminded that MySQL **still** don't have some of the basic SQL operations here is work around:

```
SELECT pc.*
FROM products_categories pc
INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr
ON (pc.category_id = pcr.category_id)
INNER JOIN products p
ON (pcr.product_id = p.product_id AND published = 0)
WHERE pc.product_category_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT distinct pc.product_category_id
    FROM products_categories pc
    INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr
    ON (pc.category_id = pcr.category_id)
    INNER JOIN products p
    ON (pcr.product_id = p.product_id AND published != 0)
)
```

or you can also make it:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT distinct pc.*
    FROM products_categories pc
    INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr
    ON (pc.category_id = pcr.category_id)
    INNER JOIN products p
    ON (pcr.product_id = p.product_id AND published = 0)
) subQ1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT distinct pc.*
    FROM products_categories pc
    INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr
    ON (pc.category_id = pcr.category_id)
    INNER JOIN products p
    ON (pcr.product_id = p.product_id AND published != 0)
) subQ2
ON subQ1.product_category_id = subQ2.product_category_id
WHERE subQ2.product_category_id IS NULL
```

I suspect the first should be faster but you can give a try to both.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `EXCEPT`

Comment: Thx for your so quick answer but… EXCEPT is not supported by MySQL :(.

Comment: OMG what's wrong with MySQL. It's not like this database is young. In any case you can work around it with some joins - let me edit

Answer (score 0):

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) might help you out here:

```
SELECT pc.`category_id`
FROM `#__products_categories` AS pc
LEFT JOIN `#__products_categories_relations` pcr 
ON pc.`category_id` = pcr.`category_id`
WHERE pcr.`category_id` IS NULL
union
select category_id
from
(
SELECT pc.`category_id`,
sum(case when p.`published`=0 then 1 else 0 end) as unpublishedProductsCount,
count(*) as allProductsCount
FROM `#__products_categories` AS pc
INNER JOIN `#__products_categories_relations` pcr 
ON pc.`category_id` = pcr.`category_id`
INNER JOIN `#__products` p on p.product_id = pcr.product_id 
GROUP BY pc.`category_id`
) t
where t.allProductsCount = t.unpublishedProductsCount
;
```

Top half above the `union` is your query to find empty categories.

Bottom half below the `union` is a query to find categories that contain exclusively products with `published=0`